# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar por columna + subfiltro 2 valores dentro de la columna que se repiten?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df= ['date', 'country', 'years']
years = 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018
```

Quiero que la columna `years` solo contenga datos de 2017 y 2018.

`df.iloc[:,2]`  ---> Con ILOC solo he podido filtrar por columna. ¿Con `iloc`, es posible filtrar por subcolumna (2017 & 2018) si los valores se repiten?

Comment: Hola Ana, este sitio es de StackOverFlow en español, por favor traduce tu pregúnta para que cumpla con las normas del sitio y podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a partir de :

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ("20/05/2006", "13/04/2017", "20/07/2016",
             "10/10/2017", "23/03/2018", "20/09/2019", "07/07/2018"), 
    "country": ("Argentina", "Bolivia", "Chile",
                "Colombia", "Ecuador", "España", "Venezuela"), 
    "years": (2006, 2017, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2018)}
    )
```

Para filtrar la columna por los dos valores necesitas aplicar un filtro boleano, bien con un `or`:

```
(df["years"] == 2017) | (df["years"] == 2018)
```

bien con `isin`:

```
df["years"].isin((2017, 2018))
```

Luego, puedes usar `iloc`, pero debes convertir la serie boleana anterior en array previamente:

```
filtro = df.iloc[df["years"].isin((2017, 2018)).to_numpy(), 2]
```

> ```
> >>> filtro
>
> 1    2017
> 3    2017
> 4    2018
> 6    2018
> ```

No obstante, `loc` es más simple e intuitivo en éste caso:

```
filtro = df.loc[df["years"].isin((2017, 2018)), "years"]
```

Ten en cuenta que si simplemente quieres filtrar las filas del DataFrame que tienen 2017 o 2018 en `years`, basta con:

```
filtro = df[df["years"].isin((2017, 2018))]
```

> ```
> >>> filtro
>
>          date    country  years
> 1  13/04/2017    Bolivia   2017
> 3  10/10/2017   Colombia   2017
> 4  23/03/2018    Ecuador   2018
> 6  07/07/2018  Venezuela   2018
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Perfecta solución, me ha sido muy útil.